# How to check the identity of elements following a certain element in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a function to check if a list contains only certain elements to the right of a different certain element and then returning a Boolean. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the positioning, how would I go about checking the list properly? Anything right of 'A' has to be `.` in order to be return `True`. If there is another string, it will be return `False`.

Example:

```
Area0   =   [['.',  '.',    'A',    'A',    '.',    '.']]
```

`right_path_clear(Area)` → True

```
Area1   =   [['.',  '.',    'A',    'A',    '.',    'e']]
```

`right_path_clear(Area)`     → False

Code I have so far:

```
def right_path_clear(area):
    for i in len(area):
        if "A" in area[i] and area == '.':
            return True
```

Comment: What is your definition of "empty"?  A zero-length string?  A space?

Comment: Are you saying you only need to know if there is one instance of `.` in the whole row, or the position of every instance of `.`?

Comment: I am confused. Why not `return area[-1] != '.'`

Comment: 'A' is a target variable for each case. '.' means its empty, but if its any letter from a-z, its occupied.  What matters is anything right of it. If its all '.' next to A then its True.

Comment: Then your current code appears to show the desired behaviour in your two examples? The issue would come if `Area1 = [['.',  '.',    'A',    'A',    'e',    '.']]` I suppose?

Comment: @AlanWakke to the right of which `'A'`? First, second?

Comment: It's always gonna be the 'A' closest to the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you do not want to use any extra method, you may create a function like:

```
def right_path_clear(area):
    for row in area:
        for content in row[::-1]: # iterate in reverse order
            if content == '.':    
                continue     # continue iteration till it receives '.'
            elif content == 'A':
                return True  # apart from '.', if 'A' is encounter first, return True
            else:
                return False  # apart from '.', if first encountered value is other than 'A', return False
```

Sample run:

```
# Example 1
>>> Area0   =   [['.',  '.',    'A',    'A',    '.',    '.']]
>>> right_path_clear(Area0)
True

# Example 2
>>> Area1   =   [['.',  '.',    'A',    'A',    '.',    'e']]
>>> right_path_clear(Area1)
False
```

Comment: Thanks, I prefer this one with the use of if and elif statements. Works well for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
def right_path_clear(area):
    for row in area:
        if ''.join(row).rstrip('.')[-1] == 'A':
            return True
    return False
```